# How is this canonical projection 1-1 and a related question

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

While self studying Field Theiry from Thomas Hunger Ford I got struck on this particular theorem (1.10) on page 236-237.

It's image:[image]

> In line 4,5 of the proof of the theorem  I am not able to get reasoning why $π $ should be monomorphism.

Also, in next line can anyone please tell how F contains π(K) ? Isn't it should be F contains π(K[x]) ?

Also, author gave no justification of why there should be π(K) is isomorphic to K. Can anyone please also tell that.?

I admit that there have been 3 questions but I didn't asked them separately as they are very much related.

Kindly guide.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

1. $\pi(K)\subset \pi(K[x])=F$
2. $\pi|_K: K \rightarrow F$ is a unital ring homomorphism. So $\operatorname{Ker}\pi|_K$ is a proper ideal of $K$. However since $K$ is a field, the only proper ideal of $K$ is $(0)$. So $\operatorname{Ker}\pi|_K=(0)$ and hence $\pi|_K$ is a monomorphism.
3. Use the logic of $2$ to deduce $\pi|_K:K \rightarrow \pi(K)$ is both a monomorphism and epimorphism, hence an isomorphism in the category of Rings.

Comment: what's "unital" ? Hungerford doesn't introduces it in his book.

Comment: I just mentioned "unital" to emphasize that the ring homomorphism takes unity to unity. Hungerford probably defines ring homomorphism this way.